# Mysql Copy Cell Data to Another Cell

Tags: mysql, copy, cell

I have a table like below. If the cell data is NULL, I want to copy the data of the other row with the same groupid. How should I run a query?

```
id|groupid|category

1 | 1     | red 
2 | 1     | red
3 | 1     | NULL
4 | 2     | NULL
5 | 2     | blue
6 | 3     | green
7 | 3     | NULL
8 | 3     | NULL
```

Final state

```
id|groupid|category

1 | 1     | red 
2 | 1     | red
3 | 1     | red
4 | 2     | blue
5 | 2     | blue
6 | 3     | green
7 | 3     | green
8 | 3     | green
```

Comment: *If the cell data is NULL, I want to copy the data of the other row with the same groupid.* From what other row precisely? if 2 or more rows in a group have values, and these values differs...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MAX` as an analytic function here:

```
SELECT
    id,
    groupid,
    MAX(category) OVER (PARTITION BY groupid) category
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    id;
```

The `MAX` function would work here, because it would ignore `NULL` values within a group, returning the non `NULL` category value.

This assumes that your intention is to assign the same color for all records in a given `groupid`.  Also, if so, then it might imply that your data model is not completely normalized, and the colors for each group should exist in a second mapping table, e.g.

```
groupid | category
1       | red
2       | blue
3       | green
```

On versions of MySQL earlier than 8+, you could use a join to achieve the same thing:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.groupid,
    t2.category
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT groupid, MAX(category) AS category
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY groupid
) t2
    ON t1.groupid = t2.groupid
ORDER BY
    id;
```

**Edit:**

For an actual *update*, you may use an update join, similar to the above:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT groupid, MAX(category) AS category
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY groupid
) t2
    ON t1.groupid = t2.groupid
SET
    t1.category = t2.category
WHERE
    t1.category IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```sql
UPDATE source_table t1
  JOIN source_table t2 USING (groupid)
SET t1.category = t2.category
WHERE t1.category IS NULL
  AND t2.category IS NOT NULL
```

If there exists more than one NOT NULL value in a group then indefinite value from all possible ones will be used (if you need some definite value in this case - specilfy the criteria).

If a group contains NULL values only, none row will be updated.